# Here maps not draggable in ms access webbrowser

Tags: ms-access, here-api

I have created a simple html using the draggable marker example from here maps. I have adapted it to support IE 11 by adding reference to legacy js, meta tag and using P2D engine in map options. Also added two url parameters for coordinates. It works perfectly in IE11 and it loads and shows pan and zoom buttons in ms-access webbrowser but it keeps static, it's not draggable, but pan and zoom works.

The curious thing is that if I navigate to wego.here.com in the same webbrowser control then the map is draggable. So they're doing something else in the here maps main page that I'm not doing in my script.

I have also tried using Microsoft Web Browser from the activex controls list in access.

I need it to be draggable so I can pick the coordinates after the user changes the marker position.

This is my script:

````
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>Draggable Marker</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
html, body { margin:0px; padding:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.main { height: 100%; }
</style>
</head> 

<body id="markers-on-the-map">

<div class="main" style="width:100%"  id="map"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="long" name="long">
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat">

<script>

function addDraggableMarker(map, behavior){

var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:latitud, lng:longitud}, {volatility: true});

  // Ensure that the marker can receive drag events
  marker.draggable = true;
  map.addObject(marker);

  // disable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // and calculate the offset between mouse and target's position
  // when starting to drag a marker object:

  map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;

    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      var targetPosition = map.geoToScreen(target.getGeometry());
      target['offset'] = new H.math.Point(pointer.viewportX - targetPosition.x, pointer.viewportY - targetPosition.y);
      behavior.disable();

    }
  }, false);


  // re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // when dragging has completed
  map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {

     $('#long').val(ev.target.b.lng);
     $('#lat').val(ev.target.b.lat);

      behavior.enable();
    }
  }, false);

  // Listen to the drag event and move the position of the marker
  // as necessary
   map.addEventListener('drag', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      target.setGeometry(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX - target['offset'].x, pointer.viewportY - target['offset'].y));
    }
  }, false);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      apikey: '?????????????????????????????????'
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//url parameters
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");


  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  }

var latitud=query_string.lat;
var longitud=query_string.long;

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Boston
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.raster.normal.map, {
  center: {lat:latitud, lng:longitud},
  engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D,
  zoom: 12,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
//window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {map.getViewPort().resize(); });

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
//var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Step 4: Create the default UI:
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, 'en-US');

// Add the click event listener.
addDraggableMarker(map, behavior);

  </script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: If you meant to include a link with `example from here maps`, it didn't work. A link would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, this is the example: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/markers/draggable-marker

Comment: I hope some engineer from Here Developer Support can bring some light to this.

Answer (score 0):

Check please on [this static page](https://alexisad.github.io/jsapi31/checkIE11.html?lat=42.35805&long=-71.0636&apiKey=%7BapiKey%7D)
: your code works for my IE11
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I mean it works in IE11 but it is not draggable in webbrowser control in ms access. Now I'm using here api to geocode addresses and leafletjs to show the map in ms access. My original code was also ramdomly freezing ms access with an OLE error.